# Server generated word file: Change default "save as" option to ".doc" instead of "website"

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word

We're having an application where we generate a .doc file on our ColdFusion server. The file opens properly in MSWord and is displayed correctly.

In Internet Explorer, it asks me wether to *download* or *save* the file. When saving, the file saves as file.doc in my download folder, which is correct.

When opening directly from Internet Explorer, the file is displayed correctly. But when I do "save as" in MSWord, the default file type is "website" and not "word document".

---

Here's the word's content. I know there are better solutions, but that's how we had it done then.

```
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
    <head>
        <title>file name goes here</title>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <xml>
        <w:WordDocument>
        <w:View>Print</w:View>
        <w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>
        <w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
        </w:WordDocument>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        <style>/*style goes here*/</style>
    </head>
    <body>body goes here</body>
</html>
```

---

I had tried to add a doctype, but nothing happened.

On ColdFusion, following happens:

```
<cfcontent reset="true" type="application/vnd.ms-word" />
#wordContent#
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=file.doc"  />
```

---

I had also tried "application/msword" as MIME-Type, but nothing happened.

I had tried to make it a .docx, but then it's malformed which seems logical, since it's not xml but html.

I hoped, there might be some meta information, which grants me access to the default file name as in e.g.

```
<o:Author>Author name goes here</o:Author>
  <o:LastAuthor>Last authors name goes here</o:LastAuthor>
  <o:Revision>1</o:Revision>
  <o:Created>#dateFormat(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")#T#timeFormat(now(),"HH:mm")#Z</o:Created>
  <o:LastSaved>#dateFormat(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")#T#timeFormat(now(),"HH:mm")#Z</o:LastSaved>
  <o:Version>12.00</o:Version>
 </o:DocumentProperties>
```

I also played with the informations given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

But none of them seemed to work. So here I am, asking for help.

Edit: Added screenshot of MSWord behaving wrong (german)

[image: saving as gives me the wrong default file type]

Comment: Is it just your filename that is wrong?  Try this:

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='attachment; filename="file.doc"'>  Some browsers like the file name wrapped in quotes too.

Comment: @steve unfortunately, this didn't work. but many thanks for the extra information, didn't know about that.

Comment: Honestly I do not think it is possible to change the default "save as type" value. While you can trick the browser into opening the content with MS Word, the program itself is still smart enough to recognize the content is HTML. So it sets the default "save as" file type accordingly. (This behavior might be part of the extension hardening changes in Office 2007, I am not sure). In any case, you can still select the `.doc` file type manually. That may be as good as it gets with psuedo-Word files like this.

Comment: @Leigh That would make sense, but I hoped that there would be a different solution. Many thanks.

Comment: The other solution would be to deliver the actual Word document instead of wrapping the content in HTML tags.

Comment: Yep, the only way to guarantee the default file type is to ensure the content matches the file extension. In the case of .doc, a true binary Word file (or possibly rtf).

Comment: @Boris - Office 2003 behaves the same, so it is not due to extension hardening. Unfortunately I think the answer is: not possible. I am going to promote the comment to answer (should have done initially).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I do not think it is possible to change the default "Save as type" value. While you can trick the browser into opening the content with MS Word, Word is still smart enough to recognize the current content is HTML. So it sets the default file type accordingly.

In any case, you can still select the `.doc` file type manually. But as long as you are generating a faux-MS Word file (ie HTML) that is probably as good as it gets.